# grplasso as a glm model

Tags: r, glm

I have many problems with 'grplasso' package. When I want to compute AIC then I had this error. How can I extract the GLM model from the grplasso function?

```
data(splice)

## Define a list with the contrasts of the factors

    contr <- rep(list("contr.sum"), ncol(splice) - 1)
    names(contr) <- names(splice)[-1]

## Fit a logistic model 
fit.splice <- grplasso(y ~ ., data = splice, model = LogReg(), lambda = 20, center = TRUE, standardize = TRUE)

AIC(fit.splice)
```

> Error in UseMethod("logLik") :    no applicable method for 'logLik'
>   applied to an object of class "grplasso"

Comment: Doesn't look like a method exists for this class of model. You can pull some stuff out of the model object e.g. `fit.splice$nloglik`

Comment: Thank you, I want to compute some performance measures for this model such as Negelkerke R2, Scaled Brier, Hosmer Lemeshow and etc. How can I do it?